# Implementing dynamic dropdown menu in django

Tags: python, django

I want to create the dynamic drop-down menu for car details

So i created four models
my models.py

```
class CompanyMake(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.company_name

class MakeModel(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyMake)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.model_name

class ModelParts(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyMake)
    model = models.ForeignKey(MakeModel)
    part_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.part_name

class ModelYear(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyMake)
    model = models.ForeignKey(MakeModel)
    year_value = models.IntegerField()


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True)   
    #image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_photo_storage_path, null = True, blank=True)
    part = models.ForeignKey(ModelParts,null = True, blank=True) 
    phone_number = models.CharField( max_length = 10,verbose_name="Mobile Number 10 digits",null = True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Now i want to create the drop-down menu for car, model, part and year
if particular car selected the all the models related to that car should get in to next model drop-down, if particular drop-down selected then all parts related to that model should get in next part drop-down menu same for the year.

My views.py

```
def home(request):
    cm = CompanyMake.objects.all()
    for a in cm:
        print a
        mm = a.makemodel_set.all()
        for b in mm:
            print b
            mp = b.modelparts_set.all()
            for c in mp:
                print c
                my = ModelYear.objects.all()
                print my

        return render(request,'choice.html',{'cm':cm,'mm':mm, 'mp':mp, 'my':my})
```

my choice.html file is

```
<select name="car">
    {% for car in cm %}

            <option value="{{car.key}}" selected="selected">{{car.company_name}}</option>

    {% endfor %}
</select>

        <br/>
```

Please guide me in right direction. i am getting only car models drop-down menu. In above way i can get all the drop-down menu but it will not be related to each other.
I want drop-down menu in related order. for car related all models should be there, for models all related parts should be there.

Comment: That's what JavaScript is for.

Comment: Can yo explain me how to do that in django using javascript. If any blog or stack overflow question?

Comment: Use Ajax, present the dropdown with the model, then when the selection has been made make an ajax request requesting the parts for the model, this prevents unnecessary requests to the database.

Comment: Is there any related question on stack overflow or any blog for the same available?

Comment: You should use Jquery, it would be easy that way.

Comment: can any one provide me the related stack overflow question or related blog or answer for this question? I am quite new for django. For reference is there any documentation available for the same.